# How to make Aysnc call in redux/reducer

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have an event handler which handles changing of state, like user input and also make API/async call. I now want to use redux to handle this.

Event handler:

```
  handleApiCall = (event) => {
    // const { arr, value } = this.state;
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
      if (value && this.someobject) {
        const arrObj = {
          name: 'Name',
          message: this.state.value,
        };
        this.state.arr.push(arrObj);
        //makes api call
        this.someobject.send("/url/sub-url", {}, JSON.stringify(arrObj));
      }
    }
  }
```

My attempt to do the same in reducer:

```
const CALL_API = 'CALL_API';

const initialState = {
  value: '',
  arr: [],
}

export default function chatWidget(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case CALL_API:
    if(action.payload === 13) {
        return {
          ...state,
          arr: [...state.arr, {name: 'Name', message: state.value}],
          value: '',
        }
    }
  }
 default:
      return state;
}
```

Now this works fine, I can see my array is being updated through my dispatch the action in component any time value is updated. But the question is where to make this api call:

```
this.someObject.send("/url/sub-url", {}, JSON.stringify(arr[something]));????
```

Answer (score 0):

**Your reducer should be pure function (now side effects like API calls).**

You have 2 options actually:

1) use thunk middleware. this is well-described [here](https://redux.js.org/advanced/async-actions)

2) use [redux-saga](https://redux-saga.js.org/) in case you want to use generators

This is basics with working on redux so read it carefuly.